# TDD should I create an empty class needed for a test case?

Tags: class, unit-testing, testing, tdd, methodology

I'm new to TDD and am keen to start using it, but I keep hitting a bump whenever a test case I'm working on requires a class that doesn't yet exist (either as an input or as an output).

The problem is that I don't know whether to create the class without any functionality (is that considered untested code or not ?), or to stop working on the test (while it's green), and start writing a test for this new non-existing class.

The second approach seems to be recursive, and might cause me to lose my train of thought, while the first creates a new class for which there's no test.

Is there a third approach I didn't think of, which is preferable ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After consulting several colleagues on this, the answer just came up to me !

When testing class A and discovering mid-test that I need a non-existing class B, I'll create B as an interface instead of as a class. This will solve the problem (i.e. an interface cannot/needn't be tested) as well as contribute to better separation and abstraction.

Answer (score 6):

You can go both ways. Sometimes, just creating a new *auxiliary* class and leave it as an empty shell for the time being is a good approach.

However, the main benefit of TDD is **feedback** about your code, so if this happens to you a lot, you should stop and consider what this tells you about the design of your API.

Still, there's nothing inherently wrong about this, because it also depends on your overall approach. If you're doing [Outside-In TDD](http://pluralsight.com/training/Courses/TableOfContents/outside-in-tdd) this would tend to happen a lot, because you start at the abstract level and work your way down (and the lover-level classes don't yet exist).

On the other hand, if you do **Bottom-Up TDD**, this shouldn't happen too often, because you start with the building blocks, and then compose higher-level classes from those building blocks.

In any case, the 'recursive' approach is an example of a situation where using [Git](http://git-scm.com/) really shines, because every time you experience that you need to write another test *before* the one you're currently writing, you can go

```
git stash
```

and then write the new test. When you're done with the new test, you can go

```
git stash pop
```

to return to the original test. You can do this recursively, so it helps you keep track of your thoughts.

Comment: Thank for the reply. My problem is that I'm trying to do "Pure" TDD, i.e. no design phase. This seems to be a real problem, since it prevents me from choosing either direction (top-down, bottom-up). It seems like I'm missing something here. How should I know where to start (which test to write first), if I'm not supposed to do any design beforehand ?

Comment: Why do you think you can't do design first? You most certainly can and should. http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/12/22/TheTDDApostate

Comment: Well, I'm basing my assumption on a lot of stuff I heard and read of Robert C. Martin and Kent Beck, who advocate that the design should spawn (for lack of a better word) from the TDD process, as well as the need to minimize the time till you write the first line of test code (i.e. little to no design time). I've read some of their books (Clean Code, Test Driven Development by example, etc.) and listened to quite a lot of their lectures on youtube, and they seem to be pretty consistent about this methodology.

Comment: What Robert C. Martin and Kent Beck says that design happens *together* with the feedback you get from TDD. None of them say that you aren't allowed to think ahead. It's perfectly fine to plan ahead, but the further ahead you plan, the more flexible those plans should be. See e.g. Robert C. Martin's book [Agile Principles, Patterns, and Practices](http://amzn.to/19W4JHk).

Comment: Robert C. Martin recently published [his current take on the subject](http://blog.8thlight.com/uncle-bob/2014/03/11/when-to-think.html). Basically, he says that you should think *before*, *during*, and even *after* TDD, which resonates well with my own experience.